# "Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h" when running Gulp Serve command

Tags: node.js, gulp

When trying to run the "Gulp" or "Gulp Serve" command I get the following error and have no idea how to resolve this, as I can't get to the file in question.

```
[16:59:39] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/Freelance/dev/shortlist/src/client-src/gulpfile.js
[16:59:39] Starting 'clean'...
[16:59:39] Finished 'clean' after 6.24 ms
[16:59:39] Starting 'default'...
[16:59:39] Starting 'sass'...
[16:59:39] Starting 'browserify'...
[16:59:39] Bundling bundle.js...


#
# Fatal error in ../deps/v8/src/handles.h, line 48
# CHECK(location_ != NULL) failed
#

==== C stack trace ===============================

 1: ??
 2: ??
 3: ??
 4: ??
 5: ??
 6: ??
 7: ??
 8: ??
 9: ??
10: ??
```

I've uninstalled + re-installed node. Removed all the modules and re-installed them, as well as uninstalled and re-installed gulp.